# Loading custom page template via plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, templates, page-template, archive-template

I am following a rather outdated tutorial on custom post types and the last step is to create a custom page template, where this is intended to show all posts of the custom type in archive listing format. As per the comments, the methods used no longer work 6 years later (go figure) and my custom page template isn't an option when creating a new page.

If I place my custom template in the theme folder it works but the option to load it from within the plugin directory has broken. How can I fix this so I can assign the template to a new page?

*Edit*

As I better understand now, this code is **only** loading the template when viewing my custom post types. The confusion was due to it showing as an available template on the "Page Attributes" section when it was located in the Themes directory. I am wanting to have it available as an option when making a new page, but have the template file located in my plugin's directory.

The original code from the tutorial:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );

function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'movie_reviews' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-movie_reviews.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-movie_reviews.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
}
```

Comment: Is your `single-movie_reviews.php` is in plugin root directory ?  Is the pasted code in the plugin too ? (I think that's not the problem but `plugin_dir_path` return the path with a `/` in the you can remove the `/` from `$template_path`)

Comment: The pasted code is in the plugin, it works if the template file is in my theme folder but not if it is located in the plugin folder. I do currently have it in the root of the plugin.

Comment: How this code is working for listing archive, for templates in theme directory, when you executed it only on single post page `is_single`?

Comment: I was curious about that as well. The code I listed is directly from the tutorial  on tutsplus.com but I tried removing the if checks and it still doesn't seem to load it.

Comment: May you try `add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1, PHP_INT_MAX);`

Comment: I just added an Edit to the original post that I think better explains it

Comment: Ok, so you want to have custom template available in Template option on single post edit administration page yes?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add custom template in page attributes template section you have to first add your template to dropdown and load it in `template_include` hook when current page has selected it as current template.

```
/**
 * Add "Custom" template to page attirbute template section.
 */
function wpse_288589_add_template_to_select( $post_templates, $wp_theme, $post, $post_type ) {

    // Add custom template named template-custom.php to select dropdown 
    $post_templates['template-custom.php'] = __('Custom');

    return $post_templates;
}

add_filter( 'theme_page_templates', 'wpse_288589_add_template_to_select', 10, 4 );


/**
 * Check if current page has our custom template. Try to load
 * template from theme directory and if not exist load it 
 * from root plugin directory.
 */
function wpse_288589_load_plugin_template( $template ) {

    if(  get_page_template_slug() === 'template-custom.php' ) {

        if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array( 'template-custom.php' ) ) ) {
            $template = $theme_file;
        } else {
            $template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'template-custom.php';
        }
    }

    if($template == '') {
        throw new \Exception('No template found');
    }

    return $template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_288589_load_plugin_template' );
```

`theme_page_templates` hook is available for `page` post type. If you want to add custom template to other post type you must replace `page` with your custom post type name e.g. `event` post type hook will have a name `theme_event_templates`.

Comment: I just added an edit to the post but basically I figured out the problem, just not sure how to solve it. What I want to do is "preload" my page template from the plugin's folder, where it can be selected when creating a new page from the dashboard. Is that possible?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: In the function "wpse_288589_add_template_to_select", where does template-custom.php reside? I changed that to the template name in my plugin directory but doesn't seem to load.

Comment: You can place it in in your theme root directory or plugin root directory. Keep in mind that in `wpse_288589_add_template_to_select` function `template-custom.php` is only a name saved to database. In `wpse_288589_load_plugin_template` I'm checking template name `template-custom.php` for current page and figure out paths by `locate_template` and  `plugin_dir_path` functions.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense, I realize how you are doing it now. I didn't think it would require such a roundabout method but that works! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Brilliant! I searched everywhere for a response! But I could not find it anywhere. Your solution fits like a glove.